# What is the word?

Tags: old-english

What is the word?
The first part is hegh (high) /if I understood correctly/

[image]

[from](https://books.google.ru/books?id=YrdRAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP163&lpg=PP163&dq=%22%C3%BEegh%22&source=bl&ots=TG7ae_t6Mp&sig=ACfU3U3FA6SXpyiwFhKlmYA1HaQ38zbDAA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjsgd2ekrzvAhWIlIsKHUl0BlgQ6AEwBXoECAcQAw#v=onepage&q=%22hegh%22&f=false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like *hegh-stald* meaning *virgin*. It’s also spelled *hægsteald*, with the etymology reported by [Revealing Words](https://litteramepandat.wordpress.com/2018/02/16/hehstald-or-haegsteald-virginity-and-celibacy-in-old-english/) as:

> the sense slips from Germanic roots of *hag* as enclosure or fence + *steald* as settlement or dwelling, to suppositions about a dependant young warrior or household retainer, hence unmarried and without his own household, to novice (*tiro*) and on to the religiously inflected celibate, and virginity.

See also

- [A Compendious Anglo-Saxon and English Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=lIAOAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=%22hegh-stald%22&source=bl&ots=jF7HJD1PBy&sig=ACfU3U2DKT3sjupnA-WLSTM9ooH-J6ANBQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiz0ZSGnLzvAhUNCM0KHZOQC90Q6AEwAXoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22hegh-stald%22&f=false)
- [A Dictionary of the Anglo-Saxon Language](https://books.google.com/books?id=oH9FAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA7-PA177&lpg=RA7-PA177&dq=%22hegh-stald%22&source=bl&ots=Ibos11Jtsn&sig=ACfU3U0vvsR_tUczeWQ4rs5-1yd9dMuQcg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj3i_D9nLzvAhVKV80KHSFtBi8Q6AEwAnoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22hegh-stald%22&f=false)